# Can't use Xamarin Android Player in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I installed Xamarin Android Player and i can only see it in Xamarin Studio but not in Visual Studio.
In the emulator dropdown menu in Visual Studio there is only the default android emulator.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, tried Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and 2015 (community editions). nothing works, what can i do?

Picture: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p13P7.jpg)

Thanks